# Is $A A^\top + I$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, transpose

Let $A$ be $n×n$ real matrix. Is $A A^\top + I$ invertible?

I know that $A^\text{*} A + I$ is invertible but don't know will it make any change for only transpose.

Comment: Try scalars first. Is $a+1$ always invertible (non zero)?

Comment: Suppose $(AA^T +I)x=0$, premultiply by $x^T$. What does that say about $x$?

Comment: @copper.hat it gives $<x,x>+ <Ax,Ax>$ which is greater then $<x,x$ , so contradiction , since $x$ should be nonzero

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the greater than part. It shows that $\|x\|^2+ \|Ax\|^2 = 0$ which implies that $x=0$. No contradiction, it shows that $AA^T+I$ is injective and hence invertible.

Comment: @Randall sorry I mistyped it

Comment: @copper.hat yeah you are correct, I assumed $x \neq 0$ on starting ,so.

Comment: @copper.hat you meant $a^2+1$ in the real case.

Comment: $AA^T$ is p.s.d and adding $I$ just shifts all the eigenvalues by $1$ (and the resulting matrix stays symmetric) so all the eigenvalues of $AA^T+I$ are $>1$. So it is indeed invertible.

Answer (score 1):

$AA^T+I$ is a (real) symmetric matrix, so it is diagonalizable. Let $AA^T+I=PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ consists of the eigenvalues of $AA^T+I$, which are real. But eigenvalues of $AA^T+I$ is grater than or equals to $1$ as $AA^T$ is a positive symmetric matrix. Hence $D$ is invertible, and so does $AA^T+I$.

Answer (score 0):

**YES** $(AA^T+I)$ is invertible, given $(A^TA+I)$ is invertible.

To prove this $C = (AA^T+I)$ is invertible -

1) C is square matrix $n * n$ (no issues).

2) We need to comment on the determinant of $C$ $\implies$.

case 1: If $A$ is invertible $\implies$ $det(AA^T+I) = det(A^{-1}).det(AA^T+I).det(A)$ and by applying $det(AB) = det(A).det(B)$ we can say $det(AA^T+I) = det(A^TA+I)$ $\implies$ our $C$ is invertible.

case 2: More generally - consider we have two matrices X = \begin{matrix}
    I & -B\\
    A & I \\
    \end{matrix}

and matrix Y =  \begin{matrix}
    I & B\\
    0 & I \\
    \end{matrix}

so here if we see $$det(X).det(Y) == det(XY) == det(I+AB)$$ and $$det(Y).det(X) == det(YX) == det(I+BA)$$ $\therefore$ we can say that $$det(X).det(Y)==det(Y).det(X)==det(I+AB)==det(I+BA)$$ for the question asked we can just put $B = A^T$ $\therefore$ it is invertible.